# discord.js Editing an embed bot message

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

Im using discord.js v12+ and Im trying to edit an embed sent by the bot but getting this error:

```
Uncaught Promise Error: 
DiscordAPIError: Cannot edit a message authored by another user
    at RequestHandler.execute (c:\Users\Kazzu\Desktop\ImmortusMC\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:170:25)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

This is my **ping.js** code:

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js')
module.exports = {
    run: async(client, message, args) => {
        const msg = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("Pong!")
        .setColor(0xE67E22)
        .setTimestamp()
        .setDescription(`API:\nWeb Socket:`);
        message.channel.send(msg)
        .then(m =>m.edit(`API: ${m.createdTimestamp - message.createdTimestamp}ms.\nWeb Socket: ${Math.round(client.ws.ping)}ms.`))
        message.edit(msg);
        message.delete()
    },
    aliases: [],
    description: 'Test API Latency'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the error because of `message.edit(msg);` since you are trying to edit the message that triggered the command.

You need to change the embed's description then edit the sent message with the updated embed.

```js
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js')
module.exports = {
  run: async (client, message, args) => {
    const msg = new MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle("Pong!")
      .setColor(0xE67E22)
      .setTimestamp()
      .setDescription(`API:\nWeb Socket:`);
    message.channel.send(msg)
      .then(m => {
        msg.setDescription(`API: ${m.createdTimestamp - message.createdTimestamp}ms.\nWeb Socket: ${Math.round(client.ws.ping)}ms.`)
        m.edit(msg)
      })
    message.delete()
  },
  aliases: [],
  description: 'Test API Latency'
}
```